# Google Analytics - how to track clicks on a screen?

Tags: google-analytics

Can I track the click of every link, button, dropdown select, etc. on a screen and have it be tracked in Google Analytics?

I want to create a page and collect data on which widget the users use most.

What about AJAX stuff?  What if you're using jQuery or Mootools...can you get the functions to register a fake URL with GA based on user interaction? I use to do this with Flash. Everytime you click a button, it can initiate a fake URL request. I would make urls such as ".../customize/eyes/" or ".../customize/nose", etc. Just wondering if I can do that with Javascript on the page.

I've also [posted at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884898/google-analytics-how-to-track-clicks-on-a-screen).

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways to do that.  To begin with Google already tracks each click you make on a link on a page.  In Google Analytics go to Content>Site Overlay

1. Use the Function PageView for Google Analytics http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html. This can be somewhat poor
2. Tools like [CrazyEgg](http://www.crazyegg.com) track specifically where each click occurs on the page, even within the link itself.  The only major downsides are that it costs money and that it has some issues with AJAX enabled code and correctly marking where someone has clicked.

Comment: There are even tools for usability testing that track all mouse movements. These are generally paid services, but they record mouse movements of visitors and then let you play them back to see how people are using your site.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally used [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) and I have heard good things about [Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/) for heatmaps and usability testing. I would recommend checking both of them out.